# Limiting grouped sets by total items

Tags: algorithm

I have a set of sets of items: `{1}, {2}, {2,3}, {13,7}, {7,2,18}`. And limits (item=>max number of items): `count(1)<=10, count(2)<=2, count(3)<=5, count(7)<=1, count(13)<=10, count(18)<=10` (no more, than 2 of `2` total). I need to find the best subset of initial set, that fits the limit. E.g., `{2}, {2,3}, {7,2,18}` doesn't fit, because it has 3 of `2` in total, but limit has only 2 of `2`.

Inner sets are immutable, e.g. `{7,2,18}` can't be split. Inner sets can be of any size (but they are about 1-5 items in practice)

The definition of "best" is kind of vague in my case. I'm ok with a subset, that have most sets. Or a subset, that has most items total.

Currently, I have this (for the case "a subset, that have most sets"):

- calculate current totals per item (`{1=>1, 2=>3, 3=>1, 7=>2, 13=>1, 18=>1}`
- find items, that are affected by limit (`{2, 7}`)
- find sets, that contain affected items (`{2}, {2,3}, {13,7}, {7,2,18}`)
- generate all subsets of this smaller set (2^4, 16 subsets, including empty)
- calculate limits for each subset
- stop with the first subset matched

My problem: I'm not sure if my solution is optimal, and it has exponential complexity.

Is there a better solution?

(In practice, it's a rare condition, that item hits limit)

Comment: BTW, if you do not know if your solution is optimal _and_ it is exponential anyway, why not just generate all possible subsets and pick the best one? That's exponential, too, but at least guaranteed to be optimal...

Answer (score 0):

The expensive step for you is to calculate all partitions of the set-of-sets to see which partitions are valid from a limits perspective. You are generating an O(2^n) tree (with n the number of initial subsets) and then looking at all leaves.

You can significantly speed this up by searching more promising candidates first, and stopping a soon as an (optimal) solution is reached. For example, going for the "subsets with most sets is best" goal, you can use the following pseudocode:

```
place initial state (= set with all subsets) S in queue Q 
do
   pop first state from Q
   if valid, return it: it is an optimal answer
      else,
         for each subset I in the current state S
             push state S-I (that is, that does not include subset I) to Q
while Q is not empty
if this line is reached, return "no answer possible"
```

Note that, in the worst case (= no possible answer), this is just as bad as what you had before. But if there are few subsets to remove, this will find them in O(2^r), where `r` is the minimal number of subsets that needs to be removed to reach an optimal answer.

You can further speed thinks up if you avoid revisiting states: an (invalid) state with `r` removed subsets will be reached `2^r` times. Note however that this is a space-time tradeoff: the larger the visited-state cache, the more memory you will need.

Other optimizations are possible, such as heuristics for choosing which subsets to remove first; for example, subsets that contain items that are currently exceeding their limits should be prioritized for removal over those that contain no such items.